# Passing multiple values in a django url with dashes

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am passing several values to a view through my url. Through some blind luck (read experienced debugging (: ) I fixed an issue I had where the view was interpreting the arguments in an unexpected fashion. The old url looked like:

```
url(r'^explore/(?P<id>[\w\-]+)-(?P<region>[\w\-]+)-(?P<location_name>[-\w]+)-(?P<page>[\w\-]+)/$',
    'project.apps.web_feed.views.display_feed', name='display_feed'),
```

My display_feed view looked like this:

```
def display_feed(request, id, region, location_name, page):
    url_scheme = id + '-' + region + '-' + location_name
    print location_name
```

There are several instances where the value for location_name was two words and the url that was called would look like this:

```
/explore/90-LA-Los-Angeles-0/
```

In my display_feed view, the value of location_name would be:

```
Angeles
```

This caused obvious problems when trying to query data and display it on the page.

When I rearranged the order of the url to have location_name as the first value like so:

```
url(r'^explore/(?P<location_name>[-\w]+)-(?P<id>[\w\-]+)-(?P<region>[\w\-]+)-(?P<page>[\w\-]+)/$',
     'heylets.apps.web_feed.views.display_search_feed', name='search_feed'),
```

and updated the view to correspond with the above changes, the logic works swimmingly and the data displays on the page as expected.

I assume there are issues with the structure of the url, but I don't want to chalk this up to inexperience and move on without first understanding what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You should chalk this up to inexperience and use ids or slugs in urls. If you absolutely must pass data in the URL, use querystrings and urlencode the data when you construct your URL. For the love of all that's holy, do not use the same character as a delimiter and as an escape character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is you were putting a ton of info in the same place without a clear delimiter. You were separating your values with a "-", but in the case of a multi-word name you were using "-" as a separator too, which can lead to unexpected results. If you are going to keep the same structure, separate your multi-word names with "_" or something different.

There may be better approaches, like the one points out: [querystring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).
You can get them on a dict and use them later, and you won't have that issue.

Another approach could be to separate your args with a different char, so your urls look like "/explore/90/LA/Los-Angeles/0/". This is the way it is shown in django tutorials and way cleaner than your approach.